# Apply mean and median in every row of a dataframe and add them as separated columns to the dataframe

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below:

```
structure(list(`2018-03` = c(NA, 943330388, NA, NA, NA, 543234645, 
45831420, NA, 27301292, 160818771), `2018-04` = c(NA, 1155823837, 
NA, NA, NA, 637460061, 38904148, NA, 39573248, 208830991), `2018-05` = c(NA, 
1360355713, NA, NA, NA, 715598918, 73012836, NA, 48043856, 189706047
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Comedy", "Education", 
"Entertainment", "Film & Animation", "Gaming", "Howto & Style", 
"Music", "People & Blogs", "Science & Technology", "Sports"))
```

and I want to create a new dataframe with row names the same as now and the 2 new columns should be the `mean` for every row, and the `median` of every row.

Comment: please try now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `rowMeans` with `rowMedians` (from `matrixStats`)

```
library(matrixStats)
library(tibble)
tibble(Mean = rowMeans(df1, na.rm = TRUE), 
      Median = rowMedians(as.matrix(df1), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: How could I also calculate range and 1st and 3rd quantiles?

Comment: @firmo23 there is `rowRanges` and `rowQuantiles` in `matrixStats` i.e. `rowRanges(as.matrix(df1), na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Yes but logically I want one column for 1st quantile one for 3rd .

Comment: Do you want `rowQuantiles(as.matrix(df1), na.rm = TRUE)[, c(2, 4)]`

Comment: YES IT IS GOOD .